# angular 13 adding [formGroup] disables routerlinkActive

Tags: html, angular, routerlinkactive

i have a navbar in my headerComponent and a button (**opens a modal which contains a sign up form**)
the problem is when i add [formGroup] to the sign up form routerlinkActive no longer works
header.component.html **navbar part**:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" id="navitem1" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"> 
        <a class="nav-link" href="" >
          <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
          Home
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="navitem2" routerLink="/orders" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="orders">
          <i class="fa fa-globe">
          </i>
          orders
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="navitem3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="services" routerLink="/services" routerLinkActive="active">
          <i class="fa fa-list">
          </i>
          sevices
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="navitem4" routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact">
          <i class="fa fa-at">
          </i>
          contact us
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

this is the sign up form code in header.component.html:

```
<form  class="form-control bg-light">
            
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
              <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c" >Nom</label>
                <input  type="text" name="name" id="name"  class="form-control" required ngModel />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
              <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Email</label>
                <input type="email"  id="email" name="email" class="form-control"  required ngModel/>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
              <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
              <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="form-control" required="true" ngModel />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
              <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
              <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                <label class="form-label" for="pwd2">Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pwd2" name="pwd2" class="form-control" required ngModel/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check d-flex mb-5"> 
              <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox"  id="check" required/>
              <label  for="check">
                I agree to all statements in <a href="#!">terms of use</a>
              </label>
            </div>
            <!-- SIGN UP BUTTON BUTTON BUTTON -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onClickSubmit()">Sign up</button>
          </form>
```

[**this is the result without [formGroup]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14tas.png)

[and this is with [formGroup]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaihn.png)

Comment: The only I can imagine is that you're using ViewEncapsulation.None in the component with the FormGroup. See if the "active" class is still added to the anchor tag when use the FormGroup or check if thre're any error in console

Answer (score 0):

by adding [formGroup] to the form and formControlName to inputs routerlinkActive no longer works you should add this to my.component.ts

```
 signupform =new FormGroup({
name:new FormControl(),
email:new FormControl(),
pwd:new FormControl(),
pwd2:new FormControl()
  });
```